# python sklearn: segmentation fault (core dump)

Tags: python-2.7, segmentation-fault, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am running sklearn (python library for machine learning), more concretely the TfifVectorizer class. When running the third line of code below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=20,  max_features=None,
    strip_accents='unicode', analyzer='word',token_pattern=r'\b[^\W\d_]+\b',
    ngram_range=(1, 5), use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1,
    stop_words = STOPWORDS)

text_tf_idf = tfv.fit_transform(s_data)
```

I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Based on the research I have done on previous similar questions, you get this error in C++ or C "when you are doing something wrong with memory".

**However, I am a bit confused because in Python you do not allocate variables to memory directly - and as far as I know the class TfifVectorizer is implemented in Python - plus I ran this code on Windows (Python 3.4) with no issues.**

Now I am running the code on Linux Ubuntu (Python 2.7).

Why is this happening and how can it be solved?

Comment: We probably cannot debug this for you. You may want to try to create a minimal dataset that reproduces this issue and open a ticket at scikit-learn's bug tracker at github.

Comment: thanks a lot Cel. good tip. will do.

Comment: ´posted on scikit-learn's bug tracker at github: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6224 . Will revert whenever I hear from them.